# Nested function not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module, powershell-workflow

Below is the file (highly simplified versions) of interest:

`main-func.psm1`:

```
function main-func
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    ()

    Write-Verbose "In main-func"
    main-workflow
}

workflow main-workflow
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    ()

    Write-Verbose "In main-workflow"
    func-outer
}

function func-outer
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    ()

    Write-Verbose "In func-outer"
    func-inner
}

function func-inner
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    ()

    Write-Verbose "In func-inner"
}

Export-ModuleMember -function main-func
```

Now I open Windows Powershell and execute the following commands:

```
> Import-Module .\main-func.psm1
> main-func -Verbose
```

The output that I get is as below:

```
VERBOSE: In main-func
VERBOSE: [localhost]:In main-workflow
VERBOSE: [localhost]:In func-outer
The term 'func-inner' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (func-inner:String) [func-outer], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,func-outer
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

But if I replace `main-workflow` in function `main-func` with `func-outer`, then it works.

I'm pretty new to Powershell and Workflows and using workflows is a requirement. Can somebody please explain what's wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at [PowerShell Workflows: Restrictions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx). I think you will find the reason there.

Comment: I checked but I could not find any obvious issues.

Comment: At the time `func-inner` is called it has not yet been declared.

Comment: @Matt When `Export-ModuleMember -function main-func` runs all functions have been created. That's all that matters.